# Searching NSString Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a string of letters and I want to search it for a specific letter.

```
NSString *word = @"word";
```

How would I find out if the string contained a letter "w"?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do it using rangeOfString:

```
NSString *word = @"word";
if ([word rangeOfString:@"w"].location == NSNotFound)
    NSLog(@"word does not contain w");
else
    NSLog(@"word contains w");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return [word rangeOfString:@"w"].location != NSNotFound;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ([word rangeOfString:@"w"].location != NSNotFound);
```