# Detecting if an NSString contains...?

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

How can I detect if a string contains a certain word? For example, I have a string below which reads:

```
@"Here is my string."
```

I'd like to know if I can detect a word in the string, such as "is" for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching NSString Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609456/searching-nsstring-cocoa)

Comment: A cheap-and-dirty solution, if the string is assumed to contain no punctuation, is to concatenate blanks on the front and back of BOTH strings, then do `rangeOfString`.

Answer (score 192):

Here's how I would do it:

```
NSString *someString = @"Here is my string";
NSRange isRange = [someString rangeOfString:@"is " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(isRange.location == 0) {
   //found it...
} else {
   NSRange isSpacedRange = [someString rangeOfString:@" is " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
   if(isSpacedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
      //found it...
   }
}
```

You can easily add this as a category onto `NSString`:

```
@interface NSString (JRStringAdditions) 

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)string;
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)string
               options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options;

@end

@implementation NSString (JRStringAdditions) 

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)string
               options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options {
   NSRange rng = [self rangeOfString:string options:options];
   return rng.location != NSNotFound;
}

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)string {
   return [self containsString:string options:0];
}

@end
```

Comment: Actually you can just add space on the beginning and end of the string and " is " will match string begins with "is"

Comment: It stuns me that these are not part of the standard class. Thanks, @Jacob!

Comment: Actually, "length" of NSRange should be tested...not "location".Here it is directly from source: "These methods return length==0 if the target string is not found. So, to check for containment: ([str rangeOfString:@"target"].length > 0).  Note that the length of the range returned by these methods might be different than the length of the target string, due composed characters and such."

Comment: Starting from iOS 8.0, there is a new method called `containsString` exposed in NSString.

Answer (score 90):

Use the following code to scan the word in sentence.

```
NSString *sentence = @"The quick brown fox";
NSString *word = @"quack";
if ([sentence rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Yes it does contain that word");
}
```

Comment: how can i get the locations when i use this method on an array?

Comment: Depends what you are using the search for in the array. Without using comparators I think the best way is to loop through the array and check each string for the search string.

NSString * searchString;
for (NSString * string in array) {
if ([string rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
                
                // Not in string
            }
            else {
                // In this string
            }
        }
You can then add the strings which do contain it to a new mutable array which enables you to show them if you are searching

Comment: ps The formatting is all correct in the code above but obviously gets mashed by being in a comment

Answer (score 23):

In iOS8 you can now use:

```
BOOL containsString = [@"Here is my string." containsString:@"is"];
```

There's an interesting post on how to "retrofit" it to iOS7 here:
http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2014/retrofitting-containsstring-on-ios-7/

Comment: It would be very nice handy method. Unfortunately it not documented and therefore is private API

Comment: It is definitely not private API. Check out the NSString.h file and you'll see it.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [NSLinguisticTagger](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html). We can use it to search `Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is?`

```
NSLinguisticTagger *linguisticTagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:@[
                                        NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType,
                                        ]
                                                                              options:
                                        NSLinguisticTaggerOmitPunctuation |
                                        NSLinguisticTaggerOmitWhitespace |
                                        NSLinguisticTaggerOmitOther ];
[linguisticTagger setString:@"Here is my string. His isn't a mississippi isthmus. It is?"];
[linguisticTagger enumerateTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,
                                                   [[linguisticTagger string] length])
                                scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType
                               options:
 NSLinguisticTaggerOmitPunctuation |
 NSLinguisticTaggerOmitWhitespace |
 NSLinguisticTaggerOmitOther |
 NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames
                            usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                NSLog(@"tag: %@, tokenRange: %@, sentenceRange: %@, token: %@",
                                      tag,
                                      NSStringFromRange(tokenRange),
                                      NSStringFromRange(sentenceRange),
                                      [[linguisticTagger string] substringWithRange:tokenRange]);
                            }];
```

This outputs:

```
tag: Word, tokenRange: {0, 4}, sentenceRange: {0, 19}, token: Here
tag: Word, tokenRange: {5, 2}, sentenceRange: {0, 19}, token: is
tag: Word, tokenRange: {8, 2}, sentenceRange: {0, 19}, token: my
tag: Word, tokenRange: {11, 6}, sentenceRange: {0, 19}, token: string
tag: Word, tokenRange: {19, 3}, sentenceRange: {19, 33}, token: His
tag: Word, tokenRange: {23, 2}, sentenceRange: {19, 33}, token: is
tag: Word, tokenRange: {25, 3}, sentenceRange: {19, 33}, token: n't
tag: Word, tokenRange: {29, 1}, sentenceRange: {19, 33}, token: a
tag: Word, tokenRange: {31, 11}, sentenceRange: {19, 33}, token: mississippi
tag: Word, tokenRange: {43, 7}, sentenceRange: {19, 33}, token: isthmus
tag: Word, tokenRange: {52, 2}, sentenceRange: {52, 6}, token: It
tag: Word, tokenRange: {55, 2}, sentenceRange: {52, 6}, token: is
```

It ignores `His` `mississippi` and `isthmus` and even identifies `is` inside of `isn't`.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you,.. add this line at .m file or create a separate class and integrate this code.

```
@implementation NSString (Contains)

- (BOOL) containsString: (NSString*) substring
{
NSRange range = [self rangeOfString : substring];
BOOL found = ( range.location != NSNotFound );
return found;
}    
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 8 and Swift, we can use localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString  method

```
 let string: NSString = "Café"
 let substring: NSString = "É"

 string.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(substring) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution would first scan for the string (without added blanks), then check if the immediately prior character is either blank or beginning of line.  Similarly check if the immediately following character is either blank or end of line.  If both tests pass then you have a match.  Depending on your needs you might also check for `,`, `.`, `()`, etc.

An alternative approach, of course, is to parse the string into words and check each word individually.