# Check whether NSString contains a comma (,)

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, string-matching

I have string separated by a comma.
First I want to check whether or not the string contains a comma.
In my app the string looks like this:

```
NSString *str=@"1,2,3";
```

How to check whether or not it contains a comma?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293499/detecting-if-an-nsstring-contains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using following code:

```
NSString *str=@"1,2,3";
NSArray *result=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
if([result count]!=0)
{
    NSLog(@"String contains comma");
}
```